# Combine two arrays into array of options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays of strings: `hrefs`, `thumbs`. Need to combine this arrays into another array with structure like below. How to do that ? For clarity - i need to use [Lightview API](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview/documentation/api) to call function `Lightview.show(elements)`, where elements is result array i need to build.

HTML:

```
<a href="/one" class="lv" thumbnail="one.jpg">one</a>
<a href="/two" class="lv" thumbnail="two.jpg">two</a>
<a href="/three" class="lv" thumbnail="three.jpg">three</a>
```

Arrays:

```
var hrefs = $('.lv').map(function() { return $(this).attr('href'); }).get();
var thumbs = $('.lv').map(function() { return $(this).attr('thumbnail'); }).get();
```

The desired result array (elements):

```
{
    {hrefs[0], 
        {
           thumbnail: thumbs[0]   
        }
    },
    {hrefs[1],
        {
           thumbnail: thumbs[1]   
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

I've started with this, but i think it is something wrong...

```
var e = new Array();
$.each(hrefs, function(i, value) {
    e[i] = new Array();
    e[i][0] = value;
    e[i][1] = {thumbnail: thumbs[i]};
});
```

Comment: Your desired result is not a valid Javascript/JSON structure. Can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: What is wrong with this structure ?

Comment: @marioosh can you give a concrete example of the desired output from the code you've shown so far?

Comment: I'm not as concerned about exactly valid syntax. I'm just not clear on what the desired data structure is.

Comment: What you're looking for can't exist in javascript. An object must be in the form `{name:value}`... you can't have `{{name:value}}`. You could do `{name1:{name2:value}}`.

Comment: It seems like what you want is `[{name:{thumbnail:value}},{name:{thumbnail:value}}]` ... is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just do:

```
var e = [];
$.each(hrefs, function(i, value) {
    e[i] = [];
    e[i] = [ value, {thumbnail: thumbs[i]} ];
});
```

Or even shorter:

```
var e = [];
$.each(hrefs, function(i, value) {
    e[i] = [ value, {thumbnail: thumbs[i]} ];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
var result = $('.lv').map(function() {
    var o = {};
    o[$(this).attr('href')] = { thumbnail: $(this).attr('thumbnail') } };
    return o;
}).get();
```

Comment: Could be wrong but I'm pretty sure you have to use bracket notation for that code to work. `var o = {}; o[$(this).attr('href')] = {thumb: ...}; return o;` Or not?

Comment: I've done that before as well, it just seems like you should be able to... Usually you can reduce to one liner if readable enough like `function func(o) {
  return o={}, o['foo'] = {a: 'baz'}, o;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var hrefs = $('.lv').map(function() { return $(this).attr('href'); }).get();
var thumbs = $('.lv').map(function() { return $(this).attr('thumbnail'); }).get();

var arr = {};
for (i in hrefs) {
    arr[hrefs[i]] = {
        thumbnail: thumbs[i]
    }
}
```

Another suggestion, with minimal use of JQuery for faster execution

```
var lvs = $('.lv');
var arr = {};
for (i=0; i< lvs.length; i++) {
    arr[lvs[i].getAttribute('href')] = {
        thumbnail: lvs[i].getAttribute('thumbnail')
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, +1 for vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result = {};

$.each( hrefs, function ( index ) {
    result[ hrefs[ index ] ] = { thumbnail: thumbs[ index ] };
});
```